# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace in OSGi (Karaf) with java standalone application

Tags: spring, osgi-bundle, karaf

While deploying the Java standalone module as bundle which has a dependency with spring modules  in Felix osgi container karaf(3.0.3). The spring 3.1.4 version is installed properly and it is imported in the bundle. However, while loading appcontext.xml through `classloader. classpathXMLApplicationContext` from the bundle, we are getting,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
```

Any help to resolve this issue?

Other details: spring-context is deployed as a seperate bundle in the osigi container(karaf).

**Question1:**
Is it possible to refer the spring-context.xsd from the bundle without any configuration changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by following the below steps. It might useful if you are migrating the existing spring project to OSGI karaf.

First of all use spring-dm feature provided by osgi container(karaf). Place the appContext-*.xml(all the spring configutration file under /META_INF/spring folder). spring-dm will take care of resolving the namespace handler and creating the application context for your project.